# TFS work item migration do not migrates work items with all links

Tags: tfs-workitem, tfs-2015, tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I have run a migration from one project to another in the different TFS Collections using TFS Integration Tool. All of the work items transferred but none of the linking occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are performing multiple Migrations, work items links will be lost when you perform multiple Migrations with the TFS integration tools.

You can try to use a “large query” to perform a migration.